# Is there a way to fix the pythonpath when using aws sam?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, pythonpath, sam

I'm trying to import a custom module that I created, but it breaks my API just to import it.

data directory:

```
-src
--order
----__init__.py
----app.py
----validator.py
----requirments.txt
--__init__.py
```

on my app.py I have this code:

```py
import json
from .validator import validate

def handler(event, context):
    msg = ''
    if event['httpMethod'] == 'GET':
        msg = "GET"
    elif event['httpMethod'] == 'POST':
        pass    #msg = validate(json.loads(event['body']))

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": msg,
        }),
    }
```

I get this error:

> Unable to import module 'app': attempted relative import with no known parent package

However, if I remove line 2 (`from .validator import validate`) from my code, it works fine, so the problem is with that `import`, and honestly, I can't figure what is going on. I have tried to import using:

```py
from src.order.validator import validate
```

but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

was able to solve my issue by generating a build through the command: sam build, and zipping my file, and putting it on the root folder inside aws-sam, it's not a great solution because I have to rebuild at every small change, but at least it's a workaround for now

Answer (score 0):

It seems `app.py` has not been loaded as part of the package hierarchy (i.e. `src` and `order` packages have not been loaded). You should be able to run

```py
from src.order import app
```

from the parent directory of `src` and your code will work. If you run `python app.py` from the terminal — which I assume is what you did — `app.py` will be run as a standalone script — not as part of a package.

However, I do not believe you need the `.validator` in your case since both modules are in the same directory. You should be able to do

```py
from validator import validate
```

Comment: I tried to make the full path import, but it doesn't work either, to run this, i invoke sam local with this command:

sam local start-api

Comment: Have tried removing the dot as suggested by the second block of code I posted? Do you get the same error?